# Can I prevent newly installed programs from superceding existing file associations?

Tags: ubuntu, kde

I use Kubuntu. Often when I install a new program it places itself at the top of the list for all applicable file associations. I generally want the new program to appear at the *bottom* of the list, so that it only opens files for which no program is already associated.

A tool to promote or demote a given program across all its file associations would also be handy.

Is this possible?